# How to assign components to a swizzled vector in WGSL?

Tags: webgpu, wgsl

I am doing some experiments with WebGPU, programming a shader in the WGSL language.
I can't figure out how to assign a 3D sub-vector to a 4D vector using swizzled indexing.
What I am trying to do is:

```
var color: vec4<f32>;
color.rgb = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); // --> error: "cannot assign to value expression of type 'vec3<f32>'"
color.a = 1.0;
```

But:

```
var color: vec4<f32>;
color.r = 0.0;
color.g = 0.0;
color.b = 0.0;
color.a = 1.0;
```

gives me the expected correct result.

What is the correct syntax to achieve this very same behavior in a single statement for the rgb components?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer lies in https://github.com/gpuweb/gpuweb/discussions/3478.

For an assignment, the left-hand side must be a reference.
Single-component accesses return a reference, so that's why *color.r = 0* works because *color.r* is a reference.

*color.rgb* however returns a value, not a reference, that's why it says you can't assign to a value expression.

can't you do *color = vec4(0,0,0,1)?*

Comment: I can't do what you are suggesting because in my case color.rgb = the_result_of_some_previous_calculation, so it's something variable.

Comment: however, I can live with the assignment of the individual values component by component: I was just hoping there was a shortcut for that long syntax, in GLSL that is a valid statement. In your Github link they say that hopefully after V1 they can enable reference for vector swizzle. Let's see. Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to do `colour = vec4(rgb_value, 1.f);` if you'd to assign it that way.